# Calculating percentage participation across columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if the question is accurate but I couldn't think of a way to put it. I am going to attempt to explain it using an example.

Consider a table of individual hospital visits with attributes for the visitID (VID), patientID (PID), and hospitalID (HID).

```
 VID  PID  HID
  1    A    x
  2    A    y
  3    A    x
  4    B    z
  5    B    z
```

What I am looking to do is identify PID-HID pairs where more than 50% of the total VIDs for that PID were at the specified HID. In this case I would want it to return "A & x" since 2/3 of the total VIDs for PID "A" were at HID "x" and "B & Z" since all of the VIDs for "B" were at "z"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be nasty, but I think it does the job.
It assumes you table is named `visits`

```
;with infoCte as (
select pid, hid, count(*) as visitcount
from visits
group by pid, hid
) 

select * 
from infocte i
where visitcount > (
    select count(*) / 2 as midcount
        from visits v
        where v.pid = i.pid
)
```

The first part gets all of the visit counts by patient and hospital.  The second part limits the results down to only those who have visited that particular hospital more than 50% of the time.  If you need exactly 50% and above change the `>` to a `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select PID,HID,100*cast(PHtotal as float)/Ptotal as PHperc
from
  (select PID,count(*) as Ptotal from tbl group by PID) t,
  (select PID,HID,count(*) as PHTotal from tbl group by PID,HID) s
where s.PID=t.PID and cast(PHtotal as float)/Ptotal>0.5
```

**EDIT**: Added missed casts to float

Comment: Although I didn't vote you down I did notice the vote occurred prior to when you corrected for the float cast.  Which is when the initial answer you provided didn't work.

Comment: Yes... Fingers faster than brain... (_I'm positive i've read this somewhere_). Anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It works on SQL 2012.

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dbd38/2/0).

```
with cte
as
(
select *, COUNT(PID) OVER(PARTITION BY PID, HID ORDER BY HID)*100.00/COUNT(PID) OVER(PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY PID) cnt
from visits
)

select *
from cte 
where cnt > 50
```

Comment: You don't need ORDER BYs in the OVER clauses, though. Also, the numerator should be `OVER (PARTITION BY PID, HID)` rather than just `OVER PARTITION BY HID)`.

Comment: Agreed, It does not make any difference.